# How can i change the font family in an iframe?

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, font-family

I use this jQuery plugin:
http://www.jqueryscript.net/text/Easy-Google-Web-Font-Selector-With-jQuery-Fontselect.html.

When I select a font from the list, I'd like the font-family in the iframe to change.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#font').fontselect().change(function(){

    // replace + signs with spaces for css
    var font = $(this).val().replace(/\+/g, ' ');

    // split font into family and weight
    font = font.split(':');

    // set family on paragraphs
    $('p').css('font-family', font[0]);
  });
});
```

```css
body { padding:50px; background-color:#333;}
p, h1 { color:#fff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-Google-Web-Font-Selector-With-jQuery-Fontselect/fontselect.css" />
<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-Google-Web-Font-Selector-With-jQuery-Fontselect/jquery.fontselect.js"></script>

<h1>jQuery Fontselect Plugin Example</h1>

<input id="font" type="text" />

<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
 Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's </p>

<iframe src="https://en.wikipedia.org" width="500px" height="500px;"/>
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Could you please check below link ? https://jsfiddle.net/bafroboq/

Comment: You should put the code in the question itself. External webpages may change, rendering the question here meaningless.

Comment: @glennsl Thank you , I put code in the question .